# How to Implement the Sub Pixel Refinement Phase in Scale Invariant Feature Transform (SIFT)

Tags: image-processing, python, edge-detection, feature-extraction, sift

I'm trying implement SIFT(Scale-invariant feature transform) myself. I've read some documents and stuck at Sub-Pixel Refinement - left without knowing how to actually implement it in code. I do understand its basic idea of estimating the pixel in continuous space using Taylor series of quadratic but how do we go differentiating "DoG function" at candidate point while it's just a series of intensities?

\begin{align}
\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}
D(\x) &= D + \frac{\partial D^{\mathrm T}}{\partial \x} \x + \frac12 \x^{\mathrm{T}} \frac{\partial^2 D}{\partial \x^2}\x
\\
\hat{\x} &= - \frac{\partial^2 D^{-1}}{\partial \x^2}\frac{\partial D}{\partial \x}
\\
D(\hat{\x}) &= D + \frac 12 \frac{\partial D^{\mathrm T}}{\partial \x}\hat{x}
\end{align}

I've encountered some discrete differentiation with Sobel operator (edge detection). Is this the case here?

My questions: What's the approach here to calculate $D(\hat{\x})$ in code, where $\hat{\x}$ is the extremum of the quadratic?